# Set font-size based on container size via CSS3

Tags: css

Is there a way to set the font-size dynamically based on the containers size with **CSS**? At the momentan I'm using the following JS code to achieve this behaviour:

```
var cubeText = function() {
    var fontSize = parseInt($(".cube.avatar").width());
    fontSizeBig = fontSize/3.5
    fontSizeSmall = fontSize/6;
    console.log(fontSize);
    $(".cube span.big").css('font-size', fontSizeBig);
    $(".cube span.small").css('font-size', fontSizeSmall);
}
```

This has one big drawback: The test pops in and after the page is loaded resized which gives a very unpleasant "ploping" effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont be possible in CSS, and/or not supported by a lot of browsers.
You can have a look at the [viewport-relative-lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) but it wont work everywhere...

For the ploping effect, you can use something like the content with the same color as the background for example, or transparency. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DVyfH/)

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
   changeFontSize();
    });

function changeFontSize(){
    var fontSize = parseInt($(".cube").width());
    var fontSizeBig = fontSize/10;
    var fontSizeSmall = fontSize/20;
    console.log(fontSize);
    $(".big").css('font-size', fontSizeBig);
    $(".small").css('font-size', fontSizeSmall);
    $(".cube").css('color','#000');
}
```

You can also use a nice js plugin like this one : http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: Thanks for the additional link to the great JS plug-in!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the CSS3 unit [`vw`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

If you need to support other browsers, JavaScript is the only way.

Comment: Also great answer,  but the unfortunately, as you said, the support is just not far enough.